# Show data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables, the first one is table name **`Post`**, the second is **`comment`**, and third is **`defineComment`**. I want to show all 3 tables, but my code is too long. Could you please advice me?

```
$r = $this->w->listwall();
    if($r)
    {
        foreach($r as $key)
        {
            // load comment to view data
            $pc['pc_comment'] = $this->w->get_comments($key['p_id']);
            $data['wall'][] = [
                'u_id'=>$key['u_id'],
                'p_id'=>$key['p_id'],
                'u_fname'=>$key['u_fname'],
                'u_lname'=>$key['u_lname'],
                'p_text'=>$key['p_text'],
                'p_date'=>$key['p_date'],
                'u_pf' =>$this->pf->getprofile($key['u_id']),
                'p_img'=>$this->w->getimg($key['p_id']),
                'cover'=>$this->w->getcoverimg($key['p_id']),
                'bgpf' =>$this->w->getbgimg($key['p_id']),
                'p_link'=>$key['p_link'],
                'pc_comment'=>$this->w->get_comments($key['p_id']),
                'pc_count'=>$this->w->get_count_comment($key['p_id']),
                'pc'=>$this->load->view('wall/v_comment_wall', $pc, TRUE),
                'p_like'=>$this->w->get_list_like($key['p_id']),
                'count_like'=>$this->w->count_like_post($key['p_id'])
            ];
        }
        $data['pf'] = $this->pf->getprofile(uid());
        //$data['edittext'] =
        //if(count($data) >= 1){
        $this->load->view('wall/v_wall',$data);
```

I also try the code below but It didn't work.

```
$r = $this->w->listwall();

foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = array($key => $value, $this->w->get_comments($value['p_id']));
}
```

Comment: Are there any dependencies between the table like foreign key relation , show the table structure

Comment: It'd be better if I upload Picture http://imgur.com/tFn6Yhc

Comment: where is define comment table you mention above

Comment: Sorry for didn't explain clearly, It's actually name "tb_post_co_rp"

Comment: so u simply want all data from these three tables

Comment: Code above works well. I want a shorter code like the below one, but It doesn't work.